# Is it ok to create a lot of tables in relational database?

Tags: database-design

I am developing website that has a photo gallery. Photos are organized in some hierarchy - they are contained in albums and albums are contained in categories.
The first thought about database design was to make 3 tables: 'photos', 'albums' and 'categories'.
Records in 'photos' have unique id - primary key and are linked to 'albums' using 'album_id' field.
Records in 'albums' also have unique id and are linked to 'categories' using 'category_id' field.

My friend who is doing frontend part of the website told me that he wants to switch between photos in album just by incrementing/decrementing photo id. With current database design it's not always possible. So the other database design that I came up with is creating a new table for each album hence I can establish 1, 2, 3, ... order for photos within an album.

Is it a good database design?
What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, front-end design (UX) should not control back-end design. It may inform it, but not control it. This is a great example of where he is taking a legitimate requirement (the need to easily move among photos of a given album), but trying to dictate a wrong DB schema model based on bad assumptions.

Your model was MUCH cleaner (one table for each entity type, such as photos, albums, and categories).  I suspect you simply need to provide an API for your backend with a method that takes an album id, and returns a list of photos in that album.  He can then sort the results and do whatever he wants with them.  That first method can either return detailed info about each photo (including full images), or abbreviated data (such as thumbnails), and allow a second method call that returns the full data/image of the photo.